# jQuery inline text scrolling/rotating/carousel effect

Tags: jquery, animation

I trying to create an animation with JQuery that scrolls 1 word in a sentence.  For example,

```
I am a nice sententce of text with a MAGIC word in it
                                     OTHER
                                     HIDDEN
                                     WORDS
```

After a second or so, MAGIC would move upwards and OTHER would scroll into view.  I've tried playing with a few carousel plugins but I can't seem to get the effect working.

Some seem to have so many nested divs that they refuse to display inline, others have issues when one word is longer than another.

Does anybody know of a plugin that could make this possible? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little more experimentation it seems that jCarousel Lite is the answer.

http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/#what

However, it does mean that the 3 elements: text before, scroll and text after have to be floated.  Not ideal, but it works!